# How to set up default value in symfony2 select box with data from database

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, repository

I have this code

```
->add('user', 'entity', array(
                            'class' => 'Acme\Entity\User',
                            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($options)
     {                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                               ->orderBy('u.name', 'ASC');
                            },
            'data' => $option['id']
            ))
```

Its not working

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)


    {
            $builder
              ->add('description')

              ->add('user', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Acme\Entity\User',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u');

                },
              'preferred_choices' => array('2')
              ))
        ;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073236/symfony2-setting-a-default-choice-field-selection

Comment: Well , i already tried that but it didn't tell when i get data from database. For array it work but its not working with query builder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the one of the following:

1. Set a default value in the object

   ```
   $cl->setUser($this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getReference('Acme:User',2));
   ```
2. Use a preferred choices option in the form builder:

   ```
   'preferred_choices' => array('2')
   ```
3. Or set `'property_path' => false` and use a `'data' => YourDefaultEnity`

Comment: 1. I can't have default value because i ma creating the user tasks and passing the userid from userpage. so depending upon the userpage in my tasks page i will have that user already setup in sleectbox. 2. REagding `prefered_choice` , it says that `The option "preferred_choice" does not exist.`

Comment: Sorry my typo. updated. And please provide a more info (controller, form builder, view) to help you

Comment: i now get this error  with choices `Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in /home/randhir/public_html/Kites/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/Type/DoctrineType.php line 88`. There is nothing special in the code. It was craeted by doctrine itself. i will add the form calss in my ques

Comment: How you call a form creation: `$form = $this->createForm(new YourType)` or `$form = $this->createForm(new YourType, new SomeObject)` ?

Comment: `$form   = $this->createForm(new MyType(), $entity,array('id' => $id));`

Comment: So `$entity` object contains a `description` and `user` fields. Right?

Comment: So, as I say, you need to:
`$entity->setUser($this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Acme:User')->find($id)); $form = $this->createForm(new MyType(), $entity);`

Answer (score 0):

The form should map the user->id value automatically to the selected entity select field. For example if your have a Computer entity that has a OnetoOne relationship with a User entity in a join table called 'computer_users':

```
class Computer{

    private $user;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ComputerUser", mappedBy="computer")
    */
    private $computerUsers;

    public function getUser(){
       return $computerUsers->getUser();
    }

    private function getComputerUser(){
       return $this->$computerUsers;
    }
}
```

The field 'user' in the form class should pick up the user->id value from the 'user' attribute object in the Computer class passed to the form.

Alternatively, you can explicitly set the value by explicitly passing the user entity into the form using SetData():

```
    $computerForm = $this->createForm( new ComputerForm(), $computer );
    $user         = $computer->getComputerUser()->getUser();

    $computerForm->get('user')->setData( $user );

    return $this->render( 'AcmeBundle:Computer:edit.html.twig'
                        , array( 'computer' => $computer
                        , 'computerForm'    => $computerForm->createView()
            )
    );
```