# How to set an option value in symfony2 entity

Tags: symfony-2.1

I'm picking information from the database in to a dropdown
and here it

```
-------------------
id     | username
-------------------
10     | llj
12     | AFS
```

How can I obtain this:

```xml
<option value="10">llj</option>
<option value="12">AFS</option>
```

in symfony2

```
->add('supervisor','entity', array(
          'class' => 'AdminBundle:supervisor',
          'expanded' => false,
          'multiple' => false,
          'placeholder'=>'',

          'empty_value' => null
            ))
```

Comment: You can see this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999745/how-to-set-up-default-value-in-symfony2-select-box-with-data-from-database

Comment: I'm finally able to achieve it in this way

on post request

'class' => 'AdminBundle:supervisor',
          

this is send and as object  so I can grap the ID which is the option value 
and send it to the controller 
 $see=$form->getData()->getSupervisor()->getStaffID();
$entity->setColumnValue($see);

that particular colum will get the ID instead of the text

I hope this will help