# Symfony2: setting the default option of a select

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form with a dropdown (select) and I would like to choose the option selected by default:

This is the code that generates the select:

```
    $builder->add('language', 'choice', array(
        'label' => 'pages.age.gateway.language.label',
        'choices' => array(1 => 'first option', 2 => 'second option'),
    ));
```

I've tried the following (suggested here, [Symfony2 Setting a default choice field selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073236/symfony2-setting-a-default-choice-field-selection)):

```
    $builder->add('language', 'choice', array(
        'label' => 'pages.age.gateway.language.label',
        'choices' => array(1 => 'first option', 2 => 'second option'),
        'data' => '2'
    ));
```

this didn't work with my code (my understanding of symfony2, I might not be in the right direction).

Another alternative would be using 'preferred_choices' but I'd like to avoid this, as I wouldn't like to modify the order in which the options are displayed.

Comment: May be array should start from `0` instead of `1`? Otherwise it is an associative array.

Comment: do it in the constructor of Entity. set default value then bind the entity to form.

Answer (score 1):

If your form depends of an entity:

```
/* Action */
public function myAction()
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->setLanguage(2); // Set the default option
    $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user); // Give the user to the form

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

            $form->bindRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {

                $user = $form->getData();
                // Do something like save / redirect
            }
     }

     return array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
     );
}
```

Also you can set a preferred choice (but not a true default value) thanks to preferred_choices key (it move up the value to the top of the select):

```
$builder->add('language', 'choice', array(
        'label' => 'pages.age.gateway.language.label',
        'choices' => array(1 => 'first option', 2 => 'second option'),
        'preferred_choices' => 2
));
```

Comment: The option 'preferred_choices' can't be an integer; it has to be traversable in some way.  It can be an array, Traversable, callable, string, or PropertyPath.  If not, you'll get an InvalidOptionsException.

Answer (score -1):

You want to add option without the value. You can do this with option `empty_value`.

```
    $builder
        ->add('gender', 'choice', array(
            'label'       => 'Gender',
            'choices' => array('male', 'female'),
            'empty_value' => 'Please select option'
    ));
```