# set checked attribute for simple checkbox field

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have the following code, which I try to pre-select the 1st and 2nd option of the checkbox when rendered. However this doesn't work. Can anyone help me why?

```
  $builder->add('preferredContactTypes', 'entity', array('class' => 'AppMainBundle:ContactType', 'property' => 'type', 'multiple' => true, 'expanded' => true, 'mapped' => false, 'data' => array(1,2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

the entity data field expects objects to be passed in not integers,

see this line:

'data'=>$em->getReference("TestGeneralBundle:Sucursal",3)

from this question:

[Symfony2 Setting a default choice field selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073236/symfony2-setting-a-default-choice-field-selection)